# Series expansion: $\frac12N(N-1)/2^N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I’m working with the expansion of typological structures and have observed the following series

$N$ = number of variables;

$\frac12N(N-1)$ = number of dyadic relationships between variables;

$2^N$ = number of typological configurations generated by N binary variables;

The series in question (for increasing N) is: $\frac12N(N-1)/(2^N)$

I studied two years university math 40 years ago – so I’m a lousy mathematician. I know that $\frac12N(N-1)$ is related to the triangular number series, determining dyadic combinations and dimensionality. But is $\frac12N(N-1)/(2^N)$ a recognized series? If so, what is it related to? Does it converge, and if so, to what?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean a *sequence* of numbers or a *series*, which is an infinite sum for $N = 1$ up to $\infty$?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I mean the latter: N=1  up to ∞.

Answer (score 1):

This series does, indeed, converge. Consider the geometric series;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n={x\over{1-x}}$$

${\space\space\space\space\space}$This holds for all $x$ such that $|x|<1$.

Taking the derivative twice on both sides of our equation yields;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}={{2\over(1-x)^2}+{2x\over(1-x)^3}}$$

Plugging in the value $x={1\over2}$ yields;

$$4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n-1)({1\over2})^{n}=16$$

$$\therefore\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(n-1)\over2^n}=4$$

Which gives us the series in question;

$$\therefore{1\over2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(n-1)\over2^n}=2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this, including (for me) a fascinating derivation.  Do you know if this series turns up in any specific applications or contexts, other than the one where I have found it.

Comment: I'm not personally aware of anywhere this particular series is applied, however, taking derivatives of geometric series pops up when deriving power series solutions to differential equations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method